# Jquery to populate <table> based on <select>

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, select, dynamic

So I've got a form with a drop down at the top that is populated with values from a mysql table.  Basically this form is to allow the addition of players to a team.

```
    $seasonid = $_SESSION['SEASON_ID'];
$sql="SELECT TEAM_ID, TEAM_NAME FROM TEAMS WHERE SEASON_ID=$seasonid";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$options="";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $tid=$row["TEAM_ID"];
        $tname=$row["TEAM_NAME"];
    $options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$tid\">".$tname;
}
```

What I'd like to do is when a team is selected from the list the database is queried with the TEAM_ID and all the players from that team are shown in a list below the form so that the person populating the form can see who is already on the team they've selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<select id = 'teamSelect'>....options....</select>
<div id = 'tableContainer'></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
    $("#teamSelect").bind("change", function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET", 
            url: "path/to/server/script.php",
            data: "tid="+$("#teamSelect").val(),
            success: function(html) {
                $("#tableContainer").html(html);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

The javascript code will perform an ajax request to a server side php script (in the code it is the `path/to/server/script.php`)  This script will query your database and simply output the table as you would like it.  The team that is selected will be in the `$_GET` variable 'tid'.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is :

```
1) attach a change handler to the dropdown using jQuery (http://api.jquery.com/change/)

2) use $.get() (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) to make an async call to the server to query the database

3) return the data (either as html directly or as a JSON See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

4) in your $.get(), success handler either :
      push the resultant html into a container element on the form (see http://api.jquery.com/html/), eg a <div> <ul> or <table> depending on what you returned from the server

or    parse the JSON and generate the html before rendering it into the form.
```

You could use the tmpl plugin to format the html if you feel brave. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/