# How to retrieve data from mysql php and show in table from dropdown

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

Hey guys i am a newbie to php.What problem i am facing is i have created a dropdown which is populated from the data from database using this code.This is working fine for me and it is populating dropdown too

```
    include('connect.php');
    $query="select * from faculty";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {$dropdown.="\r\n<option value='{$row['Designation']}'>{$row['Designation']}      </option>";}
    echo "<select>".$dropdown."</select>";
```

Solution i want is,when a user selects a value from dropdown,result should be retrieved from database and should be displayed in table.Please help me guys

Comment: i have 6 columns in my table and  i am creating a dropdown in which i am giving designation column values .So wen a user select electrical branch from it,table should display all the rows for faculty members who are from electrical branccs

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to basically :
1) Perform a form sending to some server side script(PHP in your case) when there is a change in the dropdown selection (use `onchange` event for the dropdown) and fetch the values from the db , 

2) Tell the server side script to spit out an html string which contains the table containing the desired information.3) 
3) Output the string on your page.

This will do a page refresh.

If you donot want to have a page refresh, resort to using Ajax. 
P.S. I recommend using some framework such as jQuery in case you need to use Ajax

Comment: i ll b very thankfull if u can provide me a link to the tutorial which will help me

Comment: You can have a look into these links: 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704180/jquery-to-populate-table-based-on-select 2) http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/422052/populating-a-table-from-a-selection-in-a-drop-down-menu

Comment: Answers should be marked accepted if the problem gets solved. This shows that SO is being useful in solving problems.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is something like this:

In your Html:

```
<select onchange="fetchContent()">
    <option id="1_Designation">abcd</option>
    <option id="2_Designation">1234</option>
    <option id="3_Designation">lkjh</option> 
</select>
```

In your javascript:

```
fetchContent()
{
    id = $(this).id;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/path/content.php?id="+id,
      success: function(response) {
         $("#tableRow").html(response);
      }
   });
}
```

In content.php you will have to get the value of id and then do the necessary data retrieval and then return the data.

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
//retrieve the data to $data
echo $data;
```

Comment: Nice way to give a feel of things :) I just wish to enhance this answer by changing: `$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "/path/content.php?id="+id, success: function(response) { $("#tableRow").html(response); } })` to `$.post({ "/path/content.php", {id: id}, function(response) { $("#tableRow").html(response); } })`